# Colaborate-Regular not working in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts

I am trying to use Colaborate-Regular font but its not working on Firefox and Internet explorer. This works in Chrome browser. I am trying this on local machine first but no help.

Here is the link to attachment of code.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x8nr3qyu7ztnnpu/AAAR5se5_3dRAN1Nls2F_zI8a?dl=0

Comment: instead of a  link to a dropbox file, can you please just create an [mcve](/help/mcve] using something like jsbin? Or just show that minimal code in your post? (with all due respect: we have no reason to trust a dropbox download. Put the information either in your post, or a place that immediately shows it instead of making people download potential dangers)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with dropbox link. I used that for woff,woff2 files which I cannot upload. Anyways this is very simple page. I have made a copy in JS Bin as well. https://jsbin.com/tasifasaqu/edit?html,css,console,output

Comment: one thing you can imrpove on is that you're using several formats that are no longer supported (`eot` and `svg`; one is obsolete because the versions of IE that microsoft still supports also support `woff`, so you can use that instead, and the other is literally dead. svg fonts were discontinued) as well as several formats that are literally wrapped byte-for-byte by woff (there is no need for `ttf` and `otf` sources if you also offer `woff`). So start by reducing your example to *just* woff (and woff2 if you really need it but start with just woff because it makes your testing much easier).